# Transitioning from CS50 IDE to VS Code (Import module does not work)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, python-import, cs50

I recently finished with PSET9 and wanted to transition from CS50 IDE to VS Code for the Final Project. Problem is I don't know what exactly I need to set up to make it all work. I guessed that I just need to import the CS50 library, which I then did following me checking out their GitHub. I did as instructed `pip3 install cs50`. However, even though various files were installed, my application.py is still saying that it can't find any modules, see screenshot. Why is that? What do I need to do?

Also what might I still be missing after having resolved this? Do I still need to do something to fully have the CS50 IDE essentially running on the VS Code (server, databases, etc)?

[VS Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZI7W.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create virtual environment for that and then activate it.

Create virtual environment in command line Windows

1. go to you root app folder.
2. python3 -m venv env (type this command in terminal)
3. for activate env type this in windows (env\scripts\activate)
4. for apple and linux type this in terminal) source env/bin/activate

then use pip install

Comment: I don't get the third step, I can go to the folder in the explorer and open "activate", but what do I do then? Or typing in my terminal env\scripts\activate doesn't do anything either, somehow change directory? I guess not

Comment: type this command in  VS code terminal

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, it says in the terminal that it doesn't recognize it as a name of a cmdlet nor a script file nor an executable program

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is just make sure you've got those items installed correctly by using these commands in your terminal:

```
pip show cs50
flask --version
werkzeug --version
```

If they're installed, but you haven't quit and restarted VS Code, try that.

If you're using a virtual environment, make sure you reactivate it before trying to run your application.

I hope one of these helps solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So actually what I missed saying also is that when I imported cs50, there were some yellow messages saying some parts were not on PATH. What does that mean? Not the working directory I guess. And using ´pip show cs50´ it recognizes sth. But for the other two commands nothing was found. Even though when I opened the site packages I see flask and werkzeug. Also I additionally run the command ´pip3 install flask´ to be sure, and it did install, but once again flask --version didn't recognize anything

Answer (score 0):

in my case i use [cygwin64](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html) bash to install and run the linux commands in windows 8.0  take a try it worth it and when you use it you will not need to type sudo or get-apt because there is  a big library of commands just check what do you need and you will get it ... just to make sure that the cmd will get recognize it add its path in the system environment %PATH%

Answer (score 0):

I face the same error with the cs50 library and the solution:

1. go to the error, right-click on it
2. change interpreter (choose
   the global one)

I try it myself and it works